# Can Anaconda be used to create virtual environments for Go?

Tags: python, go, anaconda, virtualenv

Anaconda is a powerful and popular toolkit normally associated to Python development. Its snake-name is probably chosen to remind of Python, but the feeling I get using it, is that all it does is handling virtual environments, pre-installing useful Python libraries, tools and packages, and then (and probably most importantly) dealing with dependencies and installations.

Can I set Anaconda up to create virtual environments for Go, too?

From the fact [Anaconda can install Go](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/go), I get to think it's actually possible, but then I also get the feeling all dependencies-solving power of Anaconda is probably made thinking of Python only.

...Can it be done?

Comment: How about using https://github.com/GetStream/vg?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas note that [vg installation](https://github.com/GetStream/vg#installation) requires an existing GO env, i.e. with `sudo` user. Anaconda on the other hand, can create GO env **without sudo** privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I also get the feeling all dependencies-solving power of Anaconda is probably made thinking of Python only.

Absolutely not.  Anaconda installs Conda.  Conda is a package and environment manager, and not just for Python, but also for R, Julia, Perl, Scala, etc... including Go.

You will need to create a new environment if you want to run Go:

```
conda create --name go --channel-name conda-forge go
```

Then move to the new environment to run go using:

```
activate go
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Go supports vendoring, you can use an utility like https://github.com/golang/dep to have all dependencies in the project.

Comment: while its not clear from the original question, the biggest advantages in using `conda` to install Go is not from the dependency management, but in the ability to install Go on systems where root access is not available and/or the user does not want a "global" software installation. `conda` isolates not just the installed libraries but the entire Go SDK as well.